# PhoneGap example app does not do anything

Tags: jailbreak, cordova

I built the PhoneGap 0.8.0 example project and then deployed it on my jailbroken iPhone.
I am using Xcode 3.2.1, and target set to "Device - 3.0 | Release"

However the PhoneGap app did not do anything, it could not get my iPhone information, and clicking the "watch accelerometer", "Get Location", etc, did not do anything.
The same thing happened if I run it on the iPhone simulator.

What have I missed?

Thanks

Comment: What version of phonegap are you using? Version of iOS? Are location services enabled in the iPhone's settings?

Comment: Have you already done device ready?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you may want to try it with a "real" iPhone.
I've known some mobile api's and services to state that they will NOT work for jail-broken phones.

Depending on how complex your application, you may want to try using their "Build" service. It's worked wonders for me!

Write your code, test in a browser...

When you're ready to test on a phone, package it up (.zip) and upload to the build service.
Within seconds (sometimes longer) you'll have compiled applications available to download.

We use it all the time - much easier than setting up your development computer.

Check it out: [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)